# xaml/wpf TabControl how to Stretch using 100% of the screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im starting working on this new world, i have some programming background but not at wpf/xaml.
Im having an issue with TabControl.

I dont know why, even using *Width="Auto"* or *HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"* i cant figure out how.

[Please see this picture to see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hMml.png)

Im trying that the ending of the tabitem goes to the end of screen use all the space on the right and get fixed, like using width=100%.

can someone help me on this please?

Thanks in advance.

here's the code

```
<DockPanel Height="auto" Width="Auto" Background="#FFF0EEEE" 
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              LastChildFill="True">
        <ScrollViewer IsTabStop="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <!--<TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Style="{DynamicResource H4}"  
                 >Start</TextBlock>-->
            <Grid Name="body" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >

                    <materialDesign:Card Padding="32" Margin="16">
                        <WrapPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Vertical"  >

                            <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource H5}">project</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium" FontSize="14.4" Style="{DynamicResource Roboto}" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TabControl Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="#0E5080" BorderThickness="1" Width="auto"  >
                                    <TabItem Header="Home 1" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                            <TextBlock>asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd </TextBlock>
                                    </TabItem>
                                    <TabItem Header="Home 2" Name="test2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                            <TextBlock>asd local</TextBlock>
                                    </TabItem>
                                    <TabItem Header="Home 3" Name="test3" Width="Auto">
                                        <TextBlock>asd ftp</TextBlock>
                                    </TabItem>
                                    <TabItem Header="Home 3">
                                        <TextBlock>asd sftp</TextBlock>
                                    </TabItem>
                                </TabControl>
                            </TextBlock>

                        </WrapPanel>
                    </materialDesign:Card>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="43*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="77*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <materialDesign:Card Padding="32" Margin="16,16,16,16" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                        <Label>asd</Label>
                    </materialDesign:Card>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I didn't try to run your xaml, but I have a few observations: 1) A TabControl inside a TextBlock? that seems a bad idea. 2) The WrapPanel also seems to me a good panel in this case, could be replaced by a StackPanel. Something that can help you is to color the background of your containers, so that you realize what element need to be set the width

Answer (score 0):

Replace the wrappanel with a stackpanel. And you had quite some strange and redundant xaml in your code (too many unused grids, textblock surrounding tabcontrol, ...). I cleaned it up a bit. You could remove the dockpanel, too, i guess.

```
<DockPanel Height="auto" Width="Auto" Background="#FFF0EEEE"
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           LastChildFill="True">
    <ScrollViewer IsTabStop="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid Name="body">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <materialDesign:Card Grid.Row="0" Padding="32" Margin="16">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource H5}">project</TextBlock>
                    <TabControl Margin="10" BorderBrush="#0E5080" BorderThickness="1">
                        <TabItem Header="Home 1">
                            <TextBlock>asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd </TextBlock>
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="Home 2" Name="test2">
                            <TextBlock>asd local</TextBlock>
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="Home 3" Name="test3">
                            <TextBlock>asd ftp</TextBlock>
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem Header="Home 3">
                            <TextBlock>asd sftp</TextBlock>
                        </TabItem>
                    </TabControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </materialDesign:Card>
            <materialDesign:Card Grid.Row="1" Padding="32" Margin="16">
                <Label>asd</Label>
            </materialDesign:Card>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Dear @Blechdose, 
Thank you so much for your answer. 
That works perfectly. i will consider your sugestions in the code. 
Sorry for the redundant things.. im learning this new world for me.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `data-binding`. If you are new to it, there are several sources out there, e.g.: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview) or [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_data_binding.htm).

Therefore you could set a name to your `WrapPanel` and bind the width of the `TabControl` to the width of the `WrapPanel`.

```
<!-- Set a name to your WrapPanel here -->
<WrapPanel x:Name="MyWrapPanel" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Vertical" >
    <TextBlock FontWeight="Medium" FontSize="14.4" >
        <!-- Set up data-binding here -->
        <TabControl Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MyWrapPanel}" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="#0E5080" BorderThickness="1">
            <TabItem IsSelected="True" Header="Home 1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock>asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd </TextBlock>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </TextBlock>
</WrapPanel>
```

Anyway I would suggest to refactor your XAML as it contains some unnecessary UI-elements.

Comment: Thank you for your help @oRole, i just tested the first solution appear here and it works.